# is it possible to use expressjs method as Restful client?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, httpclient

I want to do send request at server side to get some values from restful api.

is it possible to do something like bellow :

```html
app = require('express');

app.get("/profile-view", function(req,res){

  client = req.app;

  client.request.set('x-token','2344tgsdfsdf545hgh!'); // set header of restful request

  client.request.post('http://api.test.com/users', function(result){ //restfull post
      res.send(result);
  });

});
```

Comment: Why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: no .not yet! there are many libraries that people suggested and try those one first :D

Comment: Not as a client. Express is designed around defining an [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) that listens for incoming requests. To send them out, look into [`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) and [`http.get()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).